# Are there broken axis for pandas plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

As it is for [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html) or [broken axes](https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes).

Eg. one would want to do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

kuk = sns.load_dataset('car_crashes')

kuk.groupby("abbrev").mean().plot()
```

and would not want to have the bottom filled with too many overlapping values if there is an outlier (and yes, I know I can do it line by line and category by category but compared to the one liner...).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which Axes pandas uses to plot using the `ax=` parameter. It is therefore just a matter of plotting your data twice with the correct scale on each axes.

For instance, using pure `matplotlib` (add in all the stuff to create the broken axes effect):

```
kuk = sns.load_dataset('car_crashes')

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True)
kuk.groupby("abbrev").mean().plot(ax=ax1)
kuk.groupby("abbrev").mean().plot(ax=ax2, legend=False)

ax2.set_ylim(top=250)
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=500)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one for the given example. One could remove the upper and lower frame to create the illusion it is one graph.

Comment: Of course. The [link from the documentation provided by the OP](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html) shows how to customize the axes to give the "broken axes" look. I was just too lazy to copy and paste the whole code

Comment: I agree it's a nice work around but it's not exactly what I was heading for :). In this way one can directly use matplotlib and adjust it as you write or use broken axes as mentioned in the intro. I am, therefore, hesitant about accepting the answer. I'll wait a bit longer and see if there'll be any update here. Anyways, thanks! I very much appreciate your answer.